# When using Dijkstra's algorithm, is there a good way to keep track of a variable that changes with the path?

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph, dijkstra, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm writing a scheduling program using `C#` in which I construct a graph of people's availabilities and run Dijkstra's algorithm from every start node to every end node to determine the optimal path.

I would like to use the number of times a specific person has worked as an edge weight (i.e if the algorithm has to choose between John who has worked 2 times and Sue who has worked 1, it will choose Sue because she has worked fewer times).

The problem with this is that this number will be ever changing depending on which vertex I'm currently viewing. I think I can create a class, lets call it `TimesWorked`, that keeps a list of people and the number of times they have worked and then add an object for said class to my vertex class. From there on each edge from `vertex1` to `vertex2`, assuming this edge creates a better path to `vertex2` than current, I can deep copy `TimesWorked` from `vertex1`, make the required change to the copy, and assign that to `vertex2`. This will require me to check all paths into any vertex before checking the paths out of the vertex which should be possible because I can guarantee this is a directed acyclic graph.

I haven't written any code for the algorithm yet, otherwise I would paste it, but does anyone have any insight into whether or not my idea would work or possibly have a better idea?

here is an example graph, I made it in paint so it wasn't super easy to add arrows, but it is directed and always goes from left to right. start and end reflect the start time and end time of an availability.

[image: example graph]

Comment: Can you lay out what information your vertices shall hold and what exactly "TimesWorked" means? Is it in "Hours" or just "Number of Tasks", i.e. will a Task worth of 2 hours' work weigh more than a Task worth of 1 hour's work ... ? Maybe add a scribble pic of what you think your graph shall look like.

Comment: Perhaps just give the problem you're trying to solve rather than half-describe a solution using not-quite-Dijkstra's algorithm without detailing the problem.

Comment: Vertices will have a start time end time and person as well as TimesWorked. My current plan for TimesWorked is just number of tasks, it will probably just be a list of tuples containing a person and the number of tasks they've been assigned thus far on the current path, so I might just add the list as a property of Vertex instead of making a class to contain it. I don't know what scribble pic is, but I whipped up a quick example in Microsoft Paint that I'll add to my question.

Comment: What's the semantics of your graph? What do the vertices represent? What do the edges represent?

Comment: Can you start by describing your actual problem (you only mentioned some scheduling problem with availabilities)? The graph representation is already an attempt to solve the problem and we cannot judge whether it is a promising approach without knowing the problem. The same goes for using Dijkstra. You say that you want to use Dijkstra but this algorithm appears to be the wrong choice. So instead of trying to bend Dijkstra into something that it is not, let us help you choose a better path from the beginning ([XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).